# IndexedDB transactions to synchronize two tabs

Tags: javascript, transactions, indexeddb, webapi

I'm using IndexedDB as a data store for an application. Application state is saved to IDB on blur of certain fields. I would like for other browser tabs that have the same application open to fetch and display the most recent data on focus.

This seems to work fine in practice and I'm unable to break it, but I'd like to verify it. I can imagine a problem where if a user enters data in a field, then immediately clicks to a different window of the same application view. The first window will save data to IDB on blur, but the focus event of the other window could fire before that save has fully gone through.

I'm wondering whether using a transaction for both the write and the read would guard against that problem? Reading the [IDB spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#transaction-scheduling), I think this part seems to indicate so but I'd love for someone to validate my logic:

> Any transaction created after a read/write transaction sees the changes written by the read/write transaction. For example, if a read/write transaction A, is created, and later another transaction B, is created, and the two transactions have overlapping scopes, then transaction B sees any changes made to any object stores that are part of that overlapping scope. This also means that transaction B does not have access to any object stores in that overlapping scope until transaction A is finished.

Comment: Seems to make sense to me, so long as transactions aren't scoped to specific window which I doubt they are.

Comment: Curious what strategy is to keep various open windows synchronized? Use storage events or postMessage to warn other open windows to check for updates?